# How to get data from a .js drop down menu and load into R?

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping

I fetch data from this website every month: http://www.fiskistofa.is/english/quotas-and-catches/total-catches-by-harbours-months-and-vessel-type/ and then analyze the data with R.

I'd sure like to automate this but I have no experience with Java or Javascript. Can you tell me were to begin and guide my way into this task? Is the R language suitable?

Comment: You want to do in Java or Javascript ?

Comment: No idea about Java either. How about Javascript?

Comment: A website you given as reference is developed in JAVA language. so as your first step: just **diced** in which **technology you want to develope** your stuff....!

Comment: I just edited the question. I would like to use R if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(tibble)
library(purrr)

pg <- read_html("http://www.fiskistofa.is/english/quotas-and-catches/total-catches-by-harbours-months-and-vessel-type/")

html_nodes(pg, "select#fyrirsp>option") %>%
  map_df(~data_frame(value=html_attr(., "value"), display=html_text(., trim=TRUE)))
## # A tibble: 5 × 2
##   value                        display
##   <chr>                          <chr>
## 1  ateh              By landing harbor
## 2  hteh Main species by landing harbor
## 3  atem                       By month
## 4  ateu                 By vessel type
## 5  atev                By fishing gear
```

gets you the values in the `select` drop-down.

But, what you (probably) really need is this:

```
#' Get catch data by various parameters
#'
#' @param search_by either one of ateh, hteh, atem, ateum, atev or their display name equivalents
#' @param dagur_fra,hnappur from/to dates (either an R Date object or a date in dd.mm.yyyy string format)
#' @param lang language (prbly not relevant but it was part of the HTTP request). "en" by default and I assume a subset of ISO2C is valid
get_catch_data <- function(search_by, dagur_fra, dagur_til, lang="en") {

  require(httr)
  require(rvest)
  require(tibble)

  URL <- "http://www.fiskistofa.is/english/quotas-and-catches/total-catches-by-harbours-months-and-vessel-type/bbt.jsp"

  # this will enable us to translate the search parameter to what we need
  # match.arg also gives us error checking the param for free

  by_trans <- c(`by landing harbor`="ateh", `ateh`="ateh",
                `main species by landing harbor`="hteh", `hteh`="hteh",
                `by month`="atem", `atem`="atem",
                `by vessel type`="ateu", `ateu`="ateu",
                `by fishing gear`="atev", `atev`="atev")

  search_by <- match.arg(by_trans[tolower(search_by)],
                         c("ateh", "hteh", "atem", "ateu", "atev"))

  # if strings are not passed in for dates, make them strings

  if (inherits(dagur_fra, "Date")) dagur_fra <- format(dagur_fra, "%d.%m.%Y")
  if (inherits(dagur_til, "Date")) dagur_til <- format(dagur_til, "%d.%m.%Y")

  # shld prbly add date string format error checking code here

  # the form is submitted via HTTP POST. This fills in the form & submits it

  res <- POST(url = URL,
              query = list(lang=lang),
              body = list(fyrirsp = search_by,
                          dagurFra = dagur_fra,
                          dagurTil = dagur_til,
                          hnappur = "Enter"),
              encode = "form")

  # error checking the result (will bail if anyting but a HTTP 200 response

  stop_for_status(res)

  # parse the resultant HTML

  doc <- content(res, as="parsed")

  # find and extract the table

  # this makes an assumption that the display table always has "Total" and
  # no other tables on the page will. a somewhat fragile assumption that shld
  # be the first thing you debug if there are errors at some point down the road

  html_nodes(doc, xpath=".//table[contains(., 'Total')]") %>%
    html_table(header=TRUE) -> out

  as_tibble(out[[1]])

}
```

^^ is a function to get the data table from submitting the form. For example:

```
get_catch_data("ateh", as.Date("2016-07-01"), as.Date("2016-12-07"))
## # A tibble: 71 × 64
##                    Species Vestmannaeyjar Þorlákshöfn Grindavík Sandgerði
##                      <chr>          <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
## 1                      Cod          3.262         539     2.708       953
## 2                  Haddock          1.521         145   560.000        93
## 3                   Saithe          2.849         318   791.000       160
## 4                  Redfish          2.580         642     1.499        51
## 5                     Ling        316.000         387   216.000        41
## 6  Blueling, European ling         62.000          22    13.000         3
## 7        Tusk, torsk, cusk          8.000          50   184.000         1
## 8        Atlantic wolffish         77.000          29    83.000        14
## 9                 Monkfish         82.000          44    18.000        40
## 10      Greater argentine,          4.000           0    54.000         0
## # ... with 61 more rows, and 59 more variables: Keflavík <dbl>,
## #   Hafnarfjörður <dbl>, Kópavogur <int>, Reykjavík <dbl>, Akranes <int>,
## #   Arnarstapi <int>, Rif <dbl>, Ólafsvík <dbl>, Grundarfjörður <dbl>,
## #   Stykkishólmur <dbl>, Búðardalur <int>, Brjánslækur <int>,
## #   Patreksfjörður <dbl>, Tálknafjörður <int>, Bíldudalur <int>,
## #   Þingeyri <dbl>, Flateyri <dbl>, Suðureyri <dbl>, Bolungarvík <dbl>,
## #   Ísafjörður <dbl>, Súðavík <int>, Norðurfjörður <int>, Drangsnes <int>,
## #   Hólmavík <int>, Hvammstangi <int>, Skagaströnd <dbl>,
## #   Sauðárkrókur <dbl>, Hofsós <int>, Siglufjörður <dbl>,
## #   Ólafsfjörður <int>, Grímsey <int>, Hrísey <int>, Dalvík <dbl>,
## #   Árskógssandur <int>, Hauganes <int>, Akureyri <dbl>, Húsavík <dbl>,
## #   Kópasker <int>, Raufarhöfn <dbl>, Þórshöfn <dbl>, Bakkafjörður <int>,
## #   Vopnafjörður <dbl>, `Borgarfjörður Eystri` <int>, Seyðisfjörður <dbl>,
## #   Mjóifjörður <int>, Neskaupstaður <dbl>, Eskifjörður <dbl>,
## #   Reyðarfjörður <dbl>, Fáskrúðsfjörður <dbl>, Stöðvarfjörður <dbl>,
## #   Breiðdalsvík <int>, Djúpivogur <dbl>, Hornafjörður <dbl>, `Ýmsir
## #   staðir` <int>, Noregur <int>, Færeyjar <dbl>, Holland <dbl>,
## #   Skarðsstöð <int>, Total <dbl>
```

and:

```
get_catch_data("atem", as.Date("2016-07-01"), as.Date("2016-07-31"))
## # A tibble: 50 × 3
##                    Species `July      2016`   Total
##                      <chr>            <dbl>   <dbl>
## 1                      Cod           13.908  13.908
## 2                  Haddock            2.063   2.063
## 3                   Saithe            5.539   5.539
## 4                  Redfish            4.265   4.265
## 5                     Ling          302.000 302.000
## 6  Blueling, European ling           38.000  38.000
## 7        Tusk, torsk, cusk           29.000  29.000
## 8        Atlantic wolffish          506.000 506.000
## 9                 Monkfish          106.000 106.000
## 10      Greater argentine,          180.000 180.000
## # ... with 40 more rows
```

and:

```
get_catch_data("ateu", as.Date("2016-07-01"), as.Date("2016-12-07"))
## # A tibble: 71 × 9
##                    Species `Costal fishing` `Research vessel` Trawler
##                      <chr>            <dbl>             <int>   <dbl>
## 1                      Cod            3.747                33  47.325
## 2                  Haddock           13.000                 8   4.785
## 3                   Saithe          150.000                 4  16.182
## 4                  Redfish           46.000                28  19.330
## 5                     Ling            1.000                 0 357.000
## 6  Blueling, European ling            0.000                 1 290.000
## 7        Tusk, torsk, cusk            2.000                 0  21.000
## 8        Atlantic wolffish            2.000                 0 710.000
## 9                 Monkfish            0.000                 0  45.000
## 10      Greater argentine,            0.000                 0   1.334
## # ... with 61 more rows, and 5 more variables: `Quota vessel` <dbl>,
## #   `Small quota boat` <dbl>, `Recreational fishery` <int>, `Hook and line
## #   boat` <dbl>, Total <dbl>
```

(you get the idea).

Some notes:

- You don't need `tibble`, but I prefer using that to built-in data frame creation functions for many reasons.
- You should add more parameter error checking.
- You should prbly clean up the column names for some of the returned data frames
- You should prbly clean up (i.e. remove) the "total" fields/rows in the resultant data frame.
- I cldn't find a combination of params (on the page itself) that made "By fishing gear" return any data.