# Cannot scrape website any longer with httr and rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping

I have been scraping a table from this website succsessfully since the user [hrbrmstr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1457051/hrbrmstr) gave his answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41035278/how-to-get-data-from-a-js-drop-down-menu-and-load-into-r) of mine 5 years ago. Lately something about the website changed and I can't fetch the data any longer.

```
URL <- "http://www.fiskistofa.is/veidar/aflaupplysingar/landanir-eftir-hofnum/"
library(httr)
library(rvest)
res <- POST(url = URL,
        query = list(lang="is"),
        body = list(magn = "Sundurlidun",
                    hofn = "87",
                    dagurFra = format(lubridate::today()-4, "%d.%m.%Y"),
                    dagurTil = format(lubridate::today(), "%d.%m.%Y"),
                    hnappur = "Sækja"),
        encode = "form")
doc <- content(res, as="parsed")
```

This is how I used to be able to find and extract the table but now the output is empty:

```
  html_nodes(doc, xpath=".//table[contains(., 'Magn')]") %>%
    html_table(header=TRUE)
```

Nothing in the appearance of the site has changed but recently they opened up this [Power BI](https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiOWQ0ODAwNTgtMWViOS00YWY2LWJmNzctY2I3YjljODU2ODUwIiwidCI6Ijc2NGEzMDZkLTBhNjgtNDVhZC05ZjA3LTZmMTgwNDQ0N2NkNCIsImMiOjh9&pageName=ReportSection21d2ebb8945390a600b6) (the table is on page nr. 3) for this database so they may have changed something in the meantime that I don't know about.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what's `hofn = "87"` stand for? When I look at it in my dev tools, it looks to be `hofn = "75"`

Comment: It's one of many harbours that can be selected.

Comment: And in what form/format does `lubridate::today()` give? is it `"DD.MM.YYYY"`?

Comment: not sure what the issue is with using in R. It works fine in my environment with Python. Only thing I can think is sometimes you need to include the `user-agent` in the headers like `user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36`. But not sure the syntax to do that with R

Comment: ```lubridate::today()``` gives ```"YYYY-MM-DD"```

Comment: ok that might be the issue. It may need to be in the specific form of `"DD.MM.YYYY"`. Because the other form does not work if I try it that way in python

Comment: You are right about the date format (that was an oversight that I will change in my question) but it still does not solve my problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239671/discussion-between-valtyr-and-chitown88).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the format in the dates to `'%d.%m.%Y'`. And try changing the `http://` to `https://`

```
URL <- "https://www.fiskistofa.is/veidar/aflaupplysingar/landanir-eftir-hofnum/"
library(httr)
library(rvest)
res <- POST(url = URL,
        query = list(lang="is"),
        body = list(magn = "Sundurlidun",
                    hofn = "87",
                    dagurFra = format(lubridate::today()-4, '%d.%m.%Y') ,
                    dagurTil = format(lubridate::today(), '%d.%m.%Y'),
                    hnappur = "Sækja"),
        encode = "form")
doc <- content(res, as="parsed")
```

**In Python:**

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

url = "https://www.fiskistofa.is/veidar/aflaupplysingar/landanir-eftir-hofnum/"
today = datetime.now()    
payload = {
    'magn' : "Sundurlidun",
    'hofn' : "87",
    'dagurFra' : (today - timedelta(days=4)).strftime("%d.%m.%Y"),
    'dagurTil' : today.strftime("%d.%m.%Y"),
    'hnappur' : "Sækja"}

df = pd.read_html(requests.post(url, data=payload).text)[-1]
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
              0        1  ...                        4      5
0   Löndun dags  Skipnr.  ...               Vörutegund   Magn
1    25.11.2021     2999  ...      Steinbítur /slægður      5
2    25.11.2021     2999  ...      ÝSA/ÓSL./VS (HAFRO)    690
3    25.11.2021     2999  ...              Ýsa /óslægð    415
4    25.11.2021     2999  ...  ÞORSKUR/ÓSL./VS (HAFRO)    861
5    25.11.2021     2999  ...       Þorskur / óslægður  4.870
6    26.11.2021     2615  ...      ÝSA/ÓSL./VS (HAFRO)     14
7    26.11.2021     2615  ...              Ýsa /óslægð  1.005
8    26.11.2021     2615  ...  ÞORSKUR/ÓSL./VS (HAFRO)    164
9    26.11.2021     2615  ...       Þorskur / óslægður  1.507
10   27.11.2021     2842  ...  ÞORSKUR/ÓSL./VS (HAFRO)    271
11   27.11.2021     2842  ...       Þorskur / óslægður  5.703
12   27.11.2021     2842  ...     Þorskur-undirmál/ósl    151
13   27.11.2021     2842  ...          Hlýri /óslægður     13
14   27.11.2021     2842  ...                Gullkarfi     27
15   27.11.2021     2842  ...           Ufsi /óslægður     29
16   27.11.2021     2842  ...            Keila /óslægð     11
17   27.11.2021     2842  ...             Lýsa /óslægð      2
18   27.11.2021     2842  ...              Ýsa /óslægð  3.072
19   27.11.2021     2842  ...      Ýsa-undirmál/óslægð      8
20   28.11.2021     2256  ...              Ýsa /óslægð  1.888
21   28.11.2021     2256  ...     Þorskur-undirmál/ósl    551
22   28.11.2021     2256  ...       Þorskur / óslægður  4.212
23   28.11.2021     2256  ...      Steinbítur /slægður      4
24   28.11.2021     2256  ...      ÝSA/ÓSL./VS (HAFRO)    243
25   28.11.2021     2615  ...              Ýsa /óslægð    829
26   28.11.2021     2615  ...       Þorskur / óslægður  2.659
27   28.11.2021     2615  ...                Gullkarfi     34
28   28.11.2021     2842  ...            Keila /óslægð     11
29   28.11.2021     2842  ...                Gullkarfi     18
30   28.11.2021     2842  ...  ÞORSKUR/ÓSL./VS (HAFRO)     95
31   28.11.2021     2842  ...          Hlýri /óslægður     17
32   28.11.2021     2842  ...     Þorskur-undirmál/ósl     79
33   28.11.2021     2842  ...            Langa /óslægð     18
34   29.11.2021     1136  ...              Tindabikkja    599
35   29.11.2021     1136  ...               Þorsklifur  1.787

[36 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: Can you share the python code?

Comment: I edited the date format in the question but this doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Oh did you try `https://www.fiskistofa.is/veidar/aflaupplysingar/landanir-eftir-hofnum/` instead of `http://www.fiskistofa.is/veidar/aflaupplysingar/landanir-eftir-hofnum/`?

Comment: The change in the url was the issue all along. Problem solved.